# Particle's properties impact on radius of curvature of its path (In a uniform magnetic field)

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider 2 particles being projected into a region of uniform magnetic field (particles are projected perpendicular to the magnetic field). 
How do properties of a particle affect the radius of curvature of its path in a uniform magnetic field?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your problem, just solve $\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{ma}$ where the $\mathbf{F}$ is only due to the magnetic field. You should get that the particle goes around in a circle with radius $R = \frac{mv}{qB}$. So $B$ is given/external. However, the particle's mass, velocity, and charge still determine its radius.

If your problem isn't the very simple problem I assumed, the procedure still remains the same. Solve $\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{ma}$ and then solve for its position as a function of time. That will give you the dependence on the particles properties.